# Commands in awk

Tags: awk

Do I need to have `;` at the end of each command in `awk` files.

```
  title = gensub (beg_ere, "\\2", 1, $0);
  subtitle = gensub (beg_ere, "\\3", 1, $0);
  keywords = gensub (beg_ere, "\\4", 1, $0);

  nu = split (ukeys, uaggr, ",");
  nk = split (keywords, kaggr, ",");
```

Comment: Are you creating an `awk` code file?

Comment: Yes, I am making an `awk` code file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [awk grammar](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_16) contains the definitions:

```
program          : item_list
                 | item_list item
                 ;

item_list        : /* empty */
                 | item_list item terminator
                 ;
```

and

```
terminator       : terminator NEWLINE
                 |            ';'
                 |            NEWLINE
                 ;
```

So, no, you do not always need a semi-colon. Only if you are trying to put two items on the same line (ie. no newline in between).

Comment: Actually, it's probably more relevant to consider `terminated_statement`/`unterminated_statement` inside `action` but it works out about the same

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to have ; at the end of each command in awk files.

[The AWK programming language](https://archive.org/details/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7) says about **Actions** that

> Sometimes an action is very simple: a single print or assignment.
> Other times, it may be a sequence of several statements separated by
> newlines or semicolons.(...)

which means using only newline or only semicolon to separate is enough.